# update multiple records in table get values from another SQL 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to update table columns and set the values from another one 
like this

```
UPDATE dbo.TempTable t2
SET    Introd = t1.Introd, AgtCode = t1.[Agt Code], PIN = t1.PIN, IDNo = t1.[ID No] 
FROM   dbo.CustomerData t1
WHERE  t2.PolicyNo = t1.Policy
AND    t2.Prod = t1.Prod
AND    t2.Introd IS DISTINCT FROM t1.Introd
```

but it dosen't work with me,

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE
    Table_1
SET
    Table_1.FieldToBeUpdated = T2.FieldFromWhichToBeUpdated
FROM
    Table_1 T1
INNER JOIN
    Table_2 T2
ON 
    T1.ConditionFieldFromTable1 = T2.ConditionFieldFromTable2
```

Alternatively

```
UPDATE
    Table_1 T1,Table_2 T2
SET
    T1.FieldToBeUpdated = T2.FieldFromWhichToBeUpdated
WHERE
    SI.AnyField = RAN.AnyOtherField
```

Comment: There is No Idintity in the 2 table so i can't do Inner Join

Comment: Could you create a sql fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/) so that we can see what exactly the situation is?

Comment: @MMomani please have a look at the alternative I've provided, you can do any conditional checks in the other one.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using more of a Postgres format for SQL.  Here is the SQL Server equivalent:

```
UPDATE t2
    SET    Introd = t1.Introd,
           AgtCode = t1.[Agt Code],
           PIN = t1.PIN,
           IDNo = t1.[ID No] 
    FROM   dbo.TempTable t2 join
           dbo.CustomerData t1
           on t2.PolicyNo = t1.Policy and
              t2.Prod = t1.Prod and
              (t2.Introd <> t1.Introd or
               t2.Introd is NULL and t1.Introd is not NULL or
               t2.Introd is not NULL and t1.Introd is NULL
              )
```

Comment: The last condition is not equivalent to `t2.Introd IS DISTINCT FROM t1.Introd`

Comment: @ypercube . . . You are correct.  I was trying to take a shortcut.  Alas.

Answer (score 0):

the first method:

```
    UPDATE dbo.TempTable t2
    SET    t2.Introd = t1.Introd, t2.AgtCode = t1.[Agt Code], 
           t2.PIN = t1.PIN, t2.IDNo = t1.[ID No] 
    FROM t2
    LEFT JOIN dbo.CustomerData t1
    ON t2.PolicyNo = t1.Policy
    AND t2.Prod = t1.Prod
    AND t2.Introd IS DISTINCT FROM t1.Introd
```

the second method:

```
UPDATE dbo.TempTable t2
SET    t2.Introd = t1.Introd, t2.AgtCode = t1.[Agt Code], 
t2.PIN = t1.PIN, t2.IDNo = t1.[ID No]
FROM t2, dbo.CustomerData t1
where t2.PolicyNo = t1.Policy
AND t2.Prod = t1.Prod
AND t2.Introd IS DISTINCT FROM t1.Introd
```

Comment: i got the following Error   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 't2'.